# How to Display From Multiple Tables From Within View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to display data from ApplicationUser table and Listings Table in my Index view.

This is my ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    [InverseProperty("Seller")]
    public virtual ICollection<Listing> SellerListings { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Buyer")]
    public virtual ICollection<Listing> BuyerListings { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Listing Pocos

```
public class Listing
{
    public int ListingId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Seller")]
    public string SellerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Seller { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ItemCategory { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfPublish { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool SaleStatus { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Buyer")]
    public string BuyerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Buyer { get; set; }
}
```

In my Index view which has

```
@model IEnumerable<Pocos.Listing>
```

I want to display Seller(User)'s UserName which I ised

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Seller.UserName)
```

But this will display blank even though Seller is properly populated

Edit:
Could it be something wrong with my Controller and Repository
Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Listing> listing = client.GetAllListings();
        return View(listing);
```

Here is the method in my repository:

```
public List<Listing> GetAllListings()
    {
        return context.Listing.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: `DisplayNameFor` is for labels, you want `DisplayFor`.

Comment: `DisplayNameFor()` renders the name of the property (or the value of its `[Display]` attribute,  it its value

Comment: Sorry I meant to put DisplayFor in the question

Answer (score 0):

Just render the value directly using `@`:

```
<p>
    <span>User name:</span>
    @this.Model.Seller.UserName
</p>
```

If you need to perform further view-level processing you can use parentheses:

```
<p>
    <span>User name:</span>
    @( this.Model.Seller.UserName + " some concatenated string" )
</p>
```

If you do add a `[DisplayName]` attribute to the `UserName` property then you can still use `DisplayNameFor`, like so:

ApplicationUser.cs:

```
[DisplayName("User name")]
public String UserName { get; set; }
```

View.cshtml:

```
<p>
    <span>@Html.DisplayNameFor( m => m.Seller.UserName )</span>
    @( this.Model.Seller.UserName + " some concatenated string" )
</p>
```

This will aid localization in future, if you choose to, because the English-language text "User name" is not embedded in your views. You will need to use a subclass of `DisplayNameAttribute` that accepts a Resource name instead of a const string.

Note that if your Controller has a `POST` action that accepts an `IdentityUser` object your application will be vulnerable to model overwrite attacks. For this reason I do not recommend using Entity types for ViewModel data, you should have a dedicated one-way-only ViewModel for sensitive data.

Comment: @this.Model doesn't seem to have any properties

Comment: @SitongChen You need to pass in your ViewModel instance when you call `return View( model )` from your controller action.

Comment: @SitongChen I see in your post you're returning a List instead of a single instance. Update your view accordingly,